# Rails 4 root redirect_to locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to do a simple thing that a lot of localized sites have.

When you visit `www.example.com` directly, you should be redirected to default_locale(or another one based on IP address) and get `www.example.com/en` or some other locale, but it needs to be visible. Now, root page is localized, but it's not visible in the URL and I don't want people to be confused and think the site is from their own country.

I've seen some solutions like this (3.):

http://dhampik.com/blog/rails-routes-tricks-with-locales

and it does redirect to `www.example.com/en` , but there are errors in every browser

> Firefox: The page isn't redirecting properly. This problem can
>   sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

or

> Error code 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

I use a cookie to store the last chosen language if the user visited, but didn't sign up and that the next time they visit, we'll use value from the cookie to determine locale.

UPDATE:

The code is simple and very similar to what's described here:
-http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html
-http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n-revised (here it mentions infinite redirects, but when I put the code he suggested, I still don't get redirected to locale when visiting the page directly)

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope "(:locale)", :locale => /en|es/ do

  root 'static_pages#home'
  ...
  end
end
```

Comment: if you can share some code we can try to fix it instead of having to create it

Comment: What would you need? The code is very basic and almost the same as links (tutorials) I provided in the updated post.